# Array.indexedMap type mismatch

Tags: elm

It's my first day on Elm, but I can't deal with this typing issue. I try to use `Array` in my app to use `indexedMap`, but when I apply my custom function as the first argument to it, the compiler is complaining about a type mismatch, which seems not correct to me. What am I missing here?

```
main =
  let
    values = Array.fromList [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  in
    Array.indexedMap
      (addIndex values) /* <-- It tells me that it wants "Int -> b", but I would give it "Int -> Int" */
      values
    /* Should be [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10] */

addIndex values =
  \index ->
    let
      x = Maybe.withDefault 0 (Array.get index values)
    in
      x + index
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make you code compile, you need to change `addIndex` function, since `Array.indexedMap` expects a value of type `Int -> a -> b`, but `addIndex` returns a value of type `Int -> b`:

```
addIndex values =
  \index a ->
    let
      x = Maybe.withDefault 0 (Array.get index values)
    in
      x + index
```

Here is an [illustration](https://ellie-app.com/39sY7vgQ3Wqa1) of it

Anyway, you might wonder, what this another argument is for? Actually, it's an iterated value of the array, associated with the index. That means, that you don't need this line:

```
x = Maybe.withDefault 0 (Array.get index values)
```

since you already have this value in the iteration. Thus, the code can be simplified to:

```
main =
  let
    values = Array.fromList [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  in
    text (Debug.toString (Array.indexedMap addIndex values))

addIndex : Int -> Int -> Int
addIndex index x = x + index
```

Comment: Ah, so I **must** define the second parameter on the anonymous function to make it work?